# Space Partitioning

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have this situation in my pc:

- sda1 is windows partition
- sda2 is ubuntu partition

After it there is a free space of 5.7 MB. We believe that I can use it to expand windows though windows partition and free space are not contiguous?

[image: partions's situation]

Answer (score 0):

The only method is to

1. move your `/dev/sda2` 5.7GiB behind, then
2. expand your `/dev/sda1`.

Partitions are contiguous region, they cannot be fragmented.